# IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong in this Python code sample?

```
for i in range(len(Adapters)):
print Adapters[i]
```

I'm trying to list/print out the Array content but the code gives me error on print command: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: You should remove `Adapters = []` as you immediately reassign it to `objAdapt.cName`.

Comment: I cut out a pretty serious chunk of code from what was originally posted, but I think the two lines I left preserve the meaning. Please comment if this is a problem.

Comment: Seems a lot clearer, all the other lines were not related to the problem.

Comment: Voting to reopen as simply leaving out an indent is one of the the main causes of `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. The other open questions addressing this error message deal with mixing tabs and spaces and other inconsistent indentation.  This is not a mere typographical error.  It is an error made by someone that is new to programming and using Python as a first language. I stumbled across this question as I was looking for a good duplicate closing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234194).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to indent the `print` statement inside the body of the for-loop

```
for i in range(len(Adapters)):
    print Adapters[i]
```

If you want to streamline your code, the 2nd loop suggested by @jamylak is the way to go.

Comment: You are welcome, glad to be able to help. Feel free to upvote this, and to select your best answer by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: He can't upvote since he is <15 rep. I would but I have reached my daily limit :D

Comment: Oh, I didn't know there was any limit for your own questions .. I guess it shows I'm still a newbie myself :-) .. thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: What do you mean by *your own* questions? There is a limit on voting in general.

Comment: @jamylak Maybe I misunderstood your comment, but I thought if you post a question, you can always upvote responses to your own questions and also select an answer from those? Or are new users with reps of < 15 restricted from this (that'show I interpreted your comment). Maybe I need to spend more time with the various FAQs :-)

Comment: Haha don't worry it's all good. I was under the assumption that you could not vote up no matter what unless you are >= 15 rep.

Comment: **Hey Levon, I Accepted and Up voted your Answer! ;-)**

Comment: **Thank you and all of you for helping me out!!! ;-)**

Answer (score 7):

You need to indent inside the `for loop` block

```
for i in range(len(Adapters)):
    print(Adapters[i])
```

A better way would be:

```
for item in Adapters:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 4):

When you have a block that starts with a phrase that ends in a colon, you need to indent the next lines until you are done. This goes for loops, if statements, etc.

```
if 0!=-1:
    print "Good!"

while 0!=-1:
    print "BWAHAHAHA"

for i in range(1,100):
    print i

try:
    print blah
except NameError:
    print "Blah is not defined"
```

Answer (score 3):

As your error says you are missing an indentation on the second line. Unlike other languages like Java,  Python uses indentation  to determine the grouping of the statements. 
It should be:

```
for i in range(len(Adapters)):
    print Adapters[i]
```